# Mongodb export with conditional logic?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I want to export "street" : "Downstreet 34" 
 But dont export, if the source value is other than 3

**Sample 1** JSON
    "addresses" : [ {"source" : 3 , "street" : "Downstreet 34"}]
Export "street" : "Downstreet 34"

---

**Sample 2** JSON
    "addresses" : [ {"source" : 2 , "street" : "Downstreet 34"}]
Dont export "street" : "Downstreet 34"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find(
    { source: 2 },
    { street: 1}
)
```

Example that you can use to build queries like these are : [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

```
# SQL QUERY
SELECT user_id, status
FROM users
WHERE status = "A"


#mongoDB Query
db.users.find(
    { status: "A" },
    { user_id: 1, status: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

Comment: @yuenshi what he meant by export is "find", I was able to understand the non-literal meaning by reading the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --query  '{source : 3 , street : "Downstreet 34"}' --out output_file.json
```

This should run - update the query statement as required. Make required simple changes if not working.